# Why is XMLHttpRequest not working in local hosted file?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome

I'm a beginner in HTML, PHP and web programming in general.

My first project is a PHP page connected to a MySQL database. I am using this javascript code to send information to another PHP page :

```
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>ERP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="oXHR.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function DelRow(callback) 
        {
            alert("FIRSTALERT");
            var xhr = XMLHttpRequest();
            alert("SecondALERT");
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() 
            {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) 
                {
                    callback(xhr.responseText);
                }
            };
            var Comp = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("ComboBoxCompany").value);
            xhr.open("GET", "DeleteRow.php?Comp=" + Comp, true);
            xhr.send(null);
        }

        function readData(sData) 
        {
            alert(sData);
        };
    </script>
</head>
```

The function is called by this bad boy right here :

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Confirmer" name="ConfirmDel" onclick="DelRow(readData)" />
```

If you look at my javascript code, I've put 2 alert. The first one is appearing, but the second one is not. It seems like the getXMLHttpRequest is not working.

I'm using Google Chrome. I've found some thread saying that I need to execute this command line :

> C:\Users\User>C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
>   --allow-file
>   -access-from-files

But it changed nothing.

I'm in the dark and looking for some insight.

Comment: Where is `getXMLHttpRequest` defined? the ajax request has nothing to do with this problem if you're not getting the second alert, you haven't even sent the request yet by then.

Comment: calling PHP off the file system??? You need to be using a local server, that php file is not going to magically run. What is `getXMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: @epascarello It is running with XAMPP server. The page is displayed without any problem! It is really just the call of the getXMLHttpRequest that is not working after I press the button described in my post.

Comment: @Kevin B I can't tell where it is defined. I'm currently following the W3CSchool tutorial on ajax with PHP and this is how they show it. Is there another way to do so?

Comment: link to the tutorial, i have all w3schools links blocked from my search, so i wont' be able to find it.

Comment: @Kevin B  There you go : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_php.asp

Comment: that tutorial doesn't use `getXMLHttpRequest()`...

Comment: @Kevin B You are right. I just edited my question so that the good function is called. But the problem stays the same! Just so you know, this was a test I did before sending the question. I should have take it out before sending it, this was my bad.

Comment: You still aren't following the tutorial. you missed the `new` keyword.

Comment: @Kevin B Well I guess i gotta admit I did. The second alert is now displayed. If you want to elaborate about it in an answer, i'll go put it as the right answer. Thank you Kevin. Have a nice day.

Comment: To everyone reading this comment, can somebody explain to me why my question is being downvoted? I want to improve my questions since I'm probably gonna ask more of them soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't getting the second alert, you can pretty much rule out everything that comes after the second alert because none of it is going to be executed. This makes the problem VERY easy to track down, because it must be this line:

```
var xhr = XMLHttpRequest();
```

You're simply missing the `new` keyword.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Comment: Thank you again for your help!